# ios 8 layout using uitableview static cell & uitableview dynamic prototypes

Tags: ios, uitableview

I work on a app, nothing fancy, but since is my first app, there alot of stuff I never did before.
So, I'm trying to build a view like the image attached.
I've looked up on the Internet how to do something like that but I don't know what is better/cleaner way to do.
As you can see I have 3 areas: the title, the tableview in the middle and a button on the lower side.
The table will expand based on the content (3 lines or 30 lines) so the button  must move down and a scroll bar should appear. 
So, my idea:

Using a tableview having 3 static cells: one to put my title, second to put a tableview having prototypes cells, and a third one for the button.
That way I would have a scroll bar when the table in the middle grows, pushing the button.
Here I have a question: how to have the table view (the inner tableview) resize itself, pushing the height of the middle row, instead of having a fixed width with a scroll.
Is the the best way to achieve that?

Thanks for any idea.
C.C.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* you want to push the bottom UI down as the table grows? You say whether the table has 3 or 30 cells, but what if it has 300 cells? Your user then has to scroll to the bottom to reach the button and tab bar. I think you'll find that it would be better to use Auto Layout and let the table fill the screen space between the title and the button. The table will scroll so if you have 300 cells then you can scroll through inside the table's available area.

The advantage here is you won't be fighting with Auto Layout. If your user rotates an iPhone 4S into landscape you'll only have a few rows displayed but conversely if they run in portrait on an iPad you'll fill all of that space.

As for how to do it, the other advantage is that you don't need the nested table you describe. Use a constraint to attach the title label to the top layout guide, then attach the tab bar to the bottom layout guide. Put a vertical space constraint between the button and the tab bar. Finally, put vertical space constraints between the table and the title & the table and the button. (You'll need to implement constraints for the horizontal axis as well, but that's pretty simple.)

There's are refinements you can put into place if you want the table to *shrink* to fit if there are only 3 rows, but this should get you started and you may not want that anyway.

Key point: the tableView wants to scroll naturally, inside a view sized to fit the display. Don't change that behavior unless you *really* have to. Neither your users nor UIKit expects what you're trying to do, and the table is going to fight you all the way about it.

Nesting UIScrollViews (which your nested table would do) works, but it opens up a lot of bad UI flow problems. In my experience every time somebody wants nested scrollViews there's some other approach which is more "natural" to iOS interface paradigms.

If you're dead set on the UI you described I wouldn't use a table for the outer structure. Just make it a UIScrollView and calculate your content size based on the number of rows the table will display. You can actually do that, and then use Auto Layout as I described.

Comment: Hi Timothy. You maybe right. I will drop the outer table and keep my button always visible. Thanks for the tip.